# replacing a word in a string with an element from excel. Python

Tags: python, excel, regex, file, replace

I need the script to go through each line of the file and if it finds a value from excel, it would replace it

```
File:
    Port 1/1/1\n
    Description xxx\n
    Port 2/1/3\n
    Description yyy\n
    Port 3/4/2\n
    Description zzz\n
Excel:
1/1/1 - 5/5/5
3/4/2 - 6/6/6
```

I was only able to find the values from the file. but I can't figure out how to perform the replacement. any ideas?

```
import re
import pandas
excel_data_df = pandas.read_excel('swap_ports.xlsx', sheet_name='ports')
print(excel_data_df)
with open("string.txt", "r") as f:
    pattern = r'\d[/]\d[/]\w\d'
    printlines = f.readlines()
    for i in printlines:
        results = re.findall(pattern, i)
        print (results)
```

Comment: Do you already have code to read the Excel file?  You need to paste your code as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re
dict1={}
with open('r.txt','r') as file:
    f2=file.read().splitlines()
    for i in f2:
        i = i.replace(' ','')
        i = i.split('-')
        dict1[i[0]]=i[1]


with open('t.txt','r') as file:
    f1=file.read()
    final=[]

    for j in dict1.keys():
        pattern=f'^{j}$'
        f1=re.sub(pattern,dict1[j],f1)
    final.append(f1)
print(final)
# ['Port 5/5/5\\n\nDescription xxx\\n\nPort 2/1/3\\n\nDescription yyy\\n\nPort 6/6/6\\n\nDescription zzz\\n\n']
```

Comment: Thx. yes this code works. But if you add ports 1/1/15 to the file R, then this port will be replaced with 1/1/1 form T